# Is it possible to connect a Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2 without any concern to the CSI Camera Connector?

Tags: gpio, camera, temperature, servo

I have recently tried to connect the Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2 to the CSI Camera Connector on the Pi. At first, it worked properly and we could capture pictures and record videos. As part of a bachelor project we had to add a temperature sensor (DS18S20) and two servos to control the camera view.

After wiring the temperature sensor the camera didn't work anymore although the module was detected on the Pi. (raspistill/raspivid command --> camera LED turned ON --> then it stopped and an error occured) 
It seems like connecting the camera module and the temperature sensor at the same time led to an interference. What could have caused this problem? I would be really thankful for any advice to ensure that this problem won't happen again to the new camera.

Comment: Which model Pi, which operating system, how were the servos powered and connected, how was the DS18B20 powered and connected, what software were you using?

Comment: Raspberry Pi Model 3 with Raspian Stretch. At the moment we are using one servo (powered by the Raspberry Pi --> 5V) because the 2nd would need an additional power supply. The servos are connected via three GPIO Pins (2 servos -> 6 Pins) and the temp sensor is connected with a 4.7k Ω resistor + 1 wire

Comment: Except the camera module everything is connected externally on a breadboard to prevent the Raspberry Pi from damage.

Comment: Does disconnecting the temperature sensor make the camera work again?

Comment: No unfortunately not, we have tested the camera module on three different Raspberry Pis.